# Why isn't this html / css code for an exam adding space between the questions?

Tags: html, css

I am using `html` and `css` to write an exam and I have created a `<div>` class for the questions that is supposed to provide the space for the students to write their answers.

However the code does not work and I cannot figure out what the problem is.  Below is an example of the *not*-working code.

Please help me understand why this isn't working as intended.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       body, pre {
                  font-family: serif;
                  margin-left: 12%;
                  margin-right: 12%;
                  text-align: justify;
                  font-size: 110%;
                 {
       .shortAnsw {
                   padding-bottom: 5cm;
                  }
       .longAnsw  {
                   padding-bottom: 10cm;
                  }
       .answer    {
                   display: none;
                  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Exam 1</h1>
   <p>
    <strong> Please write your name only on the back of the last page of the exam. </strong> 
   </p>

  <h2>Short Answer</h2>
   <p>
    Please answer the following questions in no more than 3 sentences. 
   </p>
     <ol>
       <li>
         <div class="longAnsw">
           question 1
         </div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="shortAnsw">
           question 2
         </div>
       </li>
       <li>
         <div class="shortAnsw">
          question 3
         </div>
       </li>
      </ol>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think if you remove the typo (wrong closing bracket before `.shortAnsw`), it should run correctly. 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qbs4L/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a backwards `{`.

```
   body, pre {
              font-family: serif;
              margin-left: 12%;
              margin-right: 12%;
              text-align: justify;
              font-size: 110%;
             {
```

Comment: thank you!  I have been staring at this for like an hour and I think it would have taken me 1000 years to catch that!

Answer (score 1):

Divs are containers not text boxes.  If you want to let the user input text you have to use form tags.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

This is a brief tutorial for forms.

Comment: Did you mean em instead of centimeters?

Comment: It looks like the poster is trying to use HTML as a desktop publishing platform.

Comment: Thanks for the input, as @Diodeus points out, I am using html to make make documents that will ultimately be printed out.  I realize this is kinda like hammering a nail with a screwdriver and I would prefer to use LaTeX but it is a compromise I am making for easier collaboration.

Comment: No two browsers will print out the page the same. This is a bad idea. Make a PDF instead.